# Custom MongoDB search query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In my database I have documents which all contain the property `foo`. For each value of `foo` I have a function that either returns `true` or `false`. How can I query for all the documents for which the value of `foo` makes the function return `true`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to check if your string field's value is one of several, you need the [$in modifier](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24in).

```
db.collection.find( { field : { $in : array } } );
```

It works fast and uses index (if possible).

If your ***field*** is an array and you pass a string, use this syntax.

```
db.collection.find({array_field : string_value});
```

It will check every element in the array and, if any of them matches your string, it will return the document.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [$where](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-JavascriptExpressionsand%7B%7B%24where%7D%7D).

Example:

```
db.myCollection.find( { $where: "this.a > 3" });
db.myCollection.find( "this.a > 3" );
db.myCollection.find( { $where: function() { return this.a > 3;}});
```

Note, this is run in Javascript. This means two things.

1. You can put arbitrary Javacript into `$where` expression (the function form).
2. It'll be significantly slower than regular queries.

Comment: Is it possible to pass a function to `$where` with arguments?

Comment: You generate this function code in your app. So you can just "soft-code" argument values into it.

Comment: Thanks. It's not that pretty, but OK. I'm trying to test for object containment inside an array (see comment to Hightechrider)

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what the function is and how you are using it.  Is the function constant for any given record?  Is it even a function you can evaluate on the database server? ...

In the extreme, if you need to check this value often, you might, for example, create a field that exists only when f(foo) is true and then create a sparse index on that field.

$where may well be the solution you are looking for, but depending on the access patterns there may be a better solution.

Comment: I'm trying to check for a string in an array of strings. So I'm looking to do something like `$where: function (myString) { if (this.myArray.indexOf(myString)) { return true; } else { return false; }}`. Is there better?